# Why am I encountering an issue with the GDS library on a Neo4j Docker container on Windows, despite it working on Linux?

Tags: docker, neo4j, cypher

I'm running a Neo4j container with the GDS library installed using the following command:

> docker run --name testneo4j -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 -v
> /path/to/neo4j/data:/data -e NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/12345678 --env
> NEO4J_PLUGINS='["graph-data-science"]' -d neo4j:latest

On Linux, the query `RETURN gds.version()` works fine, indicating that the library is installed properly. However, when I run the same query on Windows 11, I get the following error:

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError Unknown function 'gds.version'
> (line 1, column 8 (offset: 7)) "EXPLAIN return gds.version()" ^

I'd like to avoid using a virtual machine and run the container on my localhost instead. Does anyone have an idea what's causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: That error usually indicates that the GDS plugin is not actually [installed](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/installation/). Check proper installation on Windows.

Comment: thanks for the reply, usually adding this to the environment does the trick on Linux: NEO4J_PLUGINS='["graph-data-science"]' , what's the difference on windows,

Comment: I was going to suggest that you create an issue, but I see that [you already did](https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/issues/429). :-)